# Django: Метод save в моделях не работает

Tags: python, django

В поле отслеживания я выбираю нужные пункты, нажимаю кнопку сохранить, и мне выводиться пусть QuerySet (В методе save я вызываю print()). Если я зайду обратно, то могу заметить, что все сохранилось. Почему мне не выводится отслеживания и как можно это починить?

models.py

```py
class Order(models.Model):
    trackings = models.ManyToManyField(Tracking, blank=True, verbose_name='Отслеживания')
    user = models.ForeignKey('account.CustomUser', on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                             null=True, blank=True, verbose_name='Пользователь')
    active = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print(self.trackings.all())
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Потому что это не сохранение модели, а сохранение many-to-many связей, за которое отвечают другие методы (забыл какие именно)

Answer (score 0):

Используйте django сигналы:

```
from django.db.models.signals import m2m_changed

def trackings_changed(sender, **kwargs):
    print(sender.trackings.all())

m2m_changed.connect(trackings_changed, sender=Order.trackings.through)
```

Сигналы вызываются в определенных моментах обработки. В данном случае, когда изменилось поле Order.trackings.